# Dynamically adjust for last row as new rows are inserted

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a loop on a set of data and need to insert new rows based on a certain criteria. However, my loop (based on the last row) is not accounting for these new rows I inserted. In my loop, I added "1" to make the adjustment. Thanks.

```
Sub myLoop()

Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For x = 1 To lastRow
  If Cells(x, 1).Value = "APHB" Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy
  End If

  If Cells(x, 1).Value = "APLB" Then
    Rows(x + 1).EntireRow.Insert

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Try working from the bottom up instead of top down. ie. `for x = lastRow to 1 step -1`

Comment: The for loop end gets set upon intialization and it can not be changed.  You will need to use a Do loop or loop from the bottom up using Step -1.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you show me for a do loop would work? Thanks.

Comment: There is an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
Sub myLoop()
Dim lastRow As Integer, x as Integer

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = 1
Do
  If Cells(x, 1) = "APHB" Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy
  ElseIf Cells(x, 1)= "APLB" Then
    Rows(x + 1).EntireRow.Insert
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  End If
  x = x + 1
while x < = lastRow

End Sub
```